Projecting world map from Equirectangular to Azimuthal Equidistant results in seam along 180th Meridian
I am attempting to reproject shapes from Equirectangular to North Pole Azimuthal Equidistant. However, I have noticed that it creates a seam along the 180th Meridian:


Notably, the polygon containing the south pole is invisible in the azimuthal equidistant projection. I have included the necessary project files in this temporary link:
https://file.io/8cNDvhm3TwKn
It will expire six months after this question is posted.
How can I re-merge the necessary polygons after reprojecting to an azimuthal equidistant projection, and retain polygons that contain the south pole?

It sounds like this is what you're after https://www.geographyrealm.com/dissolve-features-attribute-qgis/

To have a seam is normal because in the source data there are physical pairs of polygons: one on the left side and one on the right side of the dateline. Merging them by attribute once re-projected should work. Missing the south pole polygon seems to be a real issue.

Antarctica could well form an invalid polygon when reprojected
